# Comparing a '%searchstring%' with a field from a second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize if I don't make myself clear, my SQL query skills are limited to what I can find online.

I am trying to combine 2 fields from one table then compare it (= or LIKE) to a field on another table in the same database.

My example below doesn't error, it just doesn't return any data.

```
SELECT 
    CardNumber
   ,CardName
   ,(Firstname+' '+Lastname) as '%TEST%'
  From AxiomData.dbo.Cards,AxiomData.dbo.Cardholders
  WHERE '%TEST%' = AxiomData.dbo.Cards.CardName 
ORDER BY CardName ASC;
```

I need to match the CardNumber from one table with the CardName from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly and you don't have a matching column to join on from each table, move the name criteria to the `join`:

```
SELECT 
    CardNumber
   ,CardName
   ,(Firstname+' '+Lastname) as FullName
FROM AxiomData.dbo.Cards C 
   JOIN AxiomData.dbo.Cardholders CH 
       ON Firstname+' '+Lastname = C.CardName 
ORDER BY CardName ASC;
```

If you are trying to match on similar names and need to use `like`, then try something like this in your `join`:

```
ON C.CardName LIKE '%'+Firstname+'%'+Lastname+'%'
```

You may need to alias some of these columns...

Comment: @EricBruening -- glad we could help.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want a `join` between the tables.  But, the immediate problem is the `=`.  You seem to want `like`:

```
 WHERE AxiomData.dbo.Cards.CardName LIKE '%TEST%'
```

I imagine that the full query you want something like:

```
SELECT CardNumber, CardName, (Firstname+' '+Lastname) as FullName
From AxiomData.dbo.Cards c JOIN
     AxiomData.dbo.Cardholders ch
     ON c.CardNumber = ch.CardNumber
WHERE c.CardName LIKE '%TEST%'
ORDER BY c.CardName ASC;
```

However, this is just a guess.  Without sample data or the table layouts, there is no way to be sure what the proper `join` criteria are.

Comment: I like the JOIN idea but there is no CardNumber field on the CardHolders table, I am combining First and Last name from CardHolder to create something to compare to CardName from the Cards table.

ON c.CardNumber = ch.CardNumber errors out.  There are no common fields on these two tables.  That has been my biggest issue.

Comment: What common fields are there in the two tables?